# $_POST escaping ', " in PHP

Tags: php

I have a recurring problem with making forms handled by PHP: the characters `'` and `"` are always getting escaped with `\`.
This seems to happen even before the data gets to the PHP, in the `$_POST` array.
So when I insert `' " \` in the form, and print it staight away with the PHP, I get `\' \" \\`.
What is causing this, and what solution is there?

Comment: PHP should unescape these. where are you running into that its wrong?

Comment: @DanielA.White Basically, I'm getting the \ printed on my page when I `echo` the value from `$_POST`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have [`magic_quotes`](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) enabled on your server.

See for yourself with `var_dump(get_magic_quotes_gpc())`. If it prints `1`, they are enabled.

[Disable them](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php) and handle escaping yourself in the context of which it is required.

Comment: This is right. Magic quotes is deprecated a while now and will most likely be removed in one of the further PHP releases so it is a good idea to never rely on magic quotes. Also magic quotes often produces more problems then it solves.

Comment: @Hikaru-Shindo @alex Thank you for answering. I'm afraid I can't actually disable them at the moment, though I'll keep your link in mind. Untill I've worked it out with my server administrators, I'll use `stripslashes()`

Comment: You may use [set_magic_quotes_runtime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-magic-quotes-runtime.php) for the time being.

Answer (score 2):

Check your php.ini, it sounds like magic_quotes_gpc is set to On. This will result in auto-escaping behaviour. Set it to Off to disable this behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

```
$_POST = array_map("stripslashes", $_POST);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call the `stripslashes` function to strip the slashes from the post output. I think your issue may be with 'magic quotes' or similar (Deprecated now):

http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php